# How to change a <td> background color on click using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, onclick

Am new to Javascript and am trying to do exactly like the below http://jsbin.com/ajalu/40 using the DOM directly rather than using jQuery (the below uses jQuery). How would I do that?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style>
  article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
  menu, nav, section { display: block; }
  .on { background-color:red; color:#ffffff; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <table border="1" cellpadding="10">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Hello World</td>
        <td>Hello World</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hello World</td>
        <td>Hello World</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hello World</td>
        <td>Hello World</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript using jQuery:

```
$( function() {
  $('td').click( function() {
    $(this).parents('table').find('td').each( function( index, element ) {
        $(element).removeClass('on');
    } );
    $(this).addClass('on');
  } );
} );
```

Comment: What is the issue you're facing while trying to do so..?

Comment: Always put the relevant code and markup **in** the question, don't just link. Links rot, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you.

Comment: Side note: Using jQuery doesn't mean you're not using JavaScript. jQuery is a *library of utility functions*, not a language. What you mean is, "using the DOM directly rather than jQuery".

Comment: @ Crowder - Sorry for visual explanation i posted the link !

Comment: @Basky: So use the "edit" link to put the information in. (I've done it for you this time.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using just javascript, no jquery

Javascript

```
function Change(node){

 var j=document.getElementsByClassName("on");
  for(var i=0;i<j.length;i++){
    j[i].className="";
    }  
  node.className="on";  

    }
```

HTML

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="10">
      <tr >
        <td onclick="Change(this)">Hello World</td>
        <td onclick="Change(this)">Hello World</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td onclick="Change(this)">Hello World</td>
        <td onclick="Change(this)">Hello World</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td onclick="Change(this)">Hello World</td>
        <td onclick="Change(this)">Hello World</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
```

CSS

```
.on{

    background-color:red;
}
```

Fiddle:- http://jsfiddle.net/8SnHq/1/